# Makefile: a target to test for a header file

Tags: makefile

My open source project distributes a Makefile.  "make" by itself works fine as long as the user has Boost and OpenSSL installed. If not, he gets a compilation error.

I would like to show the user an error message with instructions on how to fix rather than have him discern the issue from the compiler output.

I've put together a little script to embed inside a Makefile that will do a quick and dirty compilation to validate if a prerequisite header file exists before allowing the core code to build. It shows an error message and aborts the compile if the code won't compile. It seems to work good.

```
# BOOST_INCLUDE := -I/home/jselbie/boost_1_51_0

all: myapp

testforboost.o:
    @echo "Testing for the presence of Boost header files..."
    @rm -f testforboost.o
    @echo "#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> " | $(CXX) $(BOOST_INCLUDE) -x c++ -c - -o testforboost.o 2>testerr; true
    @rm -f testerr
    @if [ -e testforboost.o ];\
    then \
        echo "Validated Boost header files are available";\
    else \
        echo "* ********************************************";\
        echo "* Error: Boost header files are not avaialble";\
        echo "* Consult the README file on how to fix";\
        echo "* ********************************************";\
        exit 1;\
    fi

myapp: testforboost.o
    $(CXX) $(BOOST_INCLUDE) myapp.cpp -o myapp
```

Is my script a good way to do this?  I'm under the assumption that it's portable beyond Linux (Solaris, BSD, MacOS). Or are there other standard practices for doing this?  I know that Autotools can do similar things, but I'm not too excited about learning all of Autotools and re-writing my Makefiles.

Comment: Of course, it's not a good time to learn Autotools, but consider using CMake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle it's possible like that.  But since you're only preprocessing, and given that you can use any command as a condition, it can be simplified to:

```
.PHONY: testforboost
testforboost:
    @echo "Testing for the presence of Boost header files..."
    @if echo "#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> " | $(CXX) -x c++ -E - >/dev/null 2>&1;\
    then \
        echo "Validated Boost header files are available";\
    else \
        echo "* ********************************************";\
        echo "* Error: Boost header files are not avaialble";\
        echo "* Consult the README file on how to fix";\
        echo "* ********************************************";\
        exit 1;\
    fi
```

OTOH, since you have the boost include path in a variable, why not just look for the file directly?  That would need some string manipulation.  Probably hard in make, but with [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) it would be `$(map $(BOOST_INCLUDE),s/^-I//)`

Comment: Cool. I like the simplification.  BOOST_INCLUDE is only meant to be the manual override for someone that doesn't have <boost/*> in their existing include path. I'll check out makeepp.